# Connecting Corda Node to PostgreSql through Kerberos config

Tags: kerberos, corda

How do we connect to PostgreSql through Kerberos? 
I tried to connect through
1. adding Kerberos module in drivers folder,
2. then adding `jaasappllication` n `kerberosservername` with db `url`
3. and providing `cfg` file to cmd param `java.security.auth.login.config=`

But while starting Corda node it throws error w/ message - 
**`no valid credentials provided..` `Mechanism Level: Failed to find kerberos tgt`**

However same is working with simple Java program.

Answer (score 0):

Kerberos is a product unrelated to R3, as of now there is no demo integration between kerberos and Corda at the moment.

Hence there is no documentation around this on the docs.corda.net. However, we are exploring the potentials of it in our research.